# SharePoint File Indexing

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, column, sharepoint-views

In a document library, I would like to show different columns at a folder level, not at an overall level.

Currently, I can see the column fields common for all the folders. Is there a way to have specific location views?

Comment: are you asking a view based on folder in document library?

Answer (score 2):

That is achievable, you have to follow the below steps:

- You have to enable the Content Type settings at Document library level.[image]
- You have to create the Folder Content types which will used for views.
- Add the desired column (which you want to show in the folder) in that content type.
- Now you have to create the view and from bottom of the page inside the folder option you have to select desired folder content type and other settings.

this blog give you step by step details about this: [Harness SharePoint Library and Folder Default Views to build more appealing solutions](https://camerondwyer.wordpress.com/2014/01/06/harness-sharepoint-default-views-at-different-navigation-hierarchy-levels-to-build-more-appealing-solutions/#folder)

Answer (score 0):

Create an subfolder content type which use folder as parent content type.

Add the subfolder content type in the document library, now you can show different columns at a subfolder content type.